# How can I determine if an object is empty or not

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a situation where I need to determine if an object is empty or not.  I cannot figure out the if statement to make this work.

```
function test_isObjectEmpty(){
  var responces = {};
//  var responces = {'test':'test'};
  var result = "";

  if (responces == {}){    // this does not work
    result ="Nothing found"; 
  } else {
    result ="Responce found";
  }
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the objects length, if 0, it's empty:

```
var obj = {};
if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0) {
  //it's empty
}
else {
  //it's not empty
}
```